# How do you delete Dropbox from OS X Yosemite?

Tags: applications, dropbox, trash, macos

So this seems like an obvious one, but after some searching around the web and Dropbox's bad help section I've really come unstuck with this.

I'm trying to delete the official Dropbox app from my Macbook and everytime I try and move the .app package to the trash by right clicking it says that it can't because the app is being used elsewhere.

Is there anyway I can go about deleting it? I've checked Force Quit and it's not there, so I'm curious how you get rid of this thing.

Comment: Is the Dropbox icon in the menu bar? Have you looked in Activity Monitor to see if there is a Dropbox process of some sort still running. If so, kill it. This help page is quite succinct and I've used it before. After following all these directions Dropbox.app still can't be trashed? https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/41

Comment: Ah thanks! There was a process running in Activity Monitor still that needed closing. I didn't even know it existed until now! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Check Activity Monitor to see if there are any Dropbox processes running. If there are, kill them, then you should be able to delete the Dropbox app. If you have used Dropbox at all, then remember that any files you synched will still be on your MacBook's HD in /Users/[your_username]/Dropbox.